# Calling Class to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a second activity that handles all the user input and another activity that handles all the data from the second activity. What I want to do is call a class "SubmitName" from the activity to the second activity so that I dont need to pass the values from second activity to the main activity anymore. Here are the codes..

MainActivity (Where the class "SubmitName" are located and values are passed.)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
TextView Name;
String lastname;
String licensenumber;
String mviolation;
String maplace;
String maddress;
String phonenumber;
String officername;
String contactnumber;
String datetime;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
RecyclerAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Violator> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    Button addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FragActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String str = intent.getStringExtra("firstname");
    lastname = intent.getStringExtra("lastname");
    licensenumber = intent.getStringExtra("licensenumber");
    mviolation = intent.getStringExtra("violation");
    maplace = intent.getStringExtra("arrestplace");
    maddress = intent.getStringExtra("address");
    phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra("phonenumber");
    contactnumber = intent.getStringExtra("contactnumber");
    officername = intent.getStringExtra("officername");
    datetime = intent.getStringExtra("datetime");
    Name.setText(str);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    readFromLocalStorage();
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            readFromLocalStorage();

        }
    };
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_bar, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.TrafficAd:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, TrafficAdvisory.class);
            this.startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void submitName(View view)
{

    String name = Name.getText().toString();
    String lname = lastname;
    String lnumber = licensenumber;
    String violation = mviolation;
    String aplace = maplace;
    String address = maddress;
    String pnumber = phonenumber;
    String cnumber = contactnumber;
    String oname = officername;
    String dtime = datetime;
    saveToAppServer(name,lname,lnumber,violation,aplace,address,pnumber,cnumber,oname,dtime);
    Name.setText("");
}

public void readFromLocalStorage()
{
    arrayList.clear();
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readFromLocalDatabase(database);

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.NAME));
        String lname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.LNAME));
        String lnumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.LNUMBER));
        String violation = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.VIOLATION));
        String aplace = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.ARRESTPLACE));
        String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.ADDRESS));
        String pnumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.PNUMBER));
        String cnumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.CNUMBER));
        String oname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.ONAME));
        String dtime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.DTIME));
        int sync_status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.SYNC_STATUS));
        arrayList.add(new Violator(name,lname,lnumber,violation,aplace,address,pnumber,cnumber,oname,dtime,sync_status));


    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cursor.close();


}

public void saveToAppServer(final String name,final String lname, final String lnumber,final String violation, final  String aplace,final String address, final String pnumber, final String cnumber, final String oname, final String dtime)
{


    if (checkNetworkConnection())
    {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,DBContract.SERVER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response){
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String Response = jsonObject.getString("response");
                            if(Response.equals("OK"))
                            {
                                saveToLocalStorage(name,lname,lnumber,violation,aplace,address,pnumber,cnumber,oname,dtime,DBContract.SYNC_STATUS_OK);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                saveToLocalStorage(name,lname,lnumber,violation,aplace,address,pnumber,cnumber,oname,dtime,DBContract.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

                saveToLocalStorage(name,lname,lnumber,violation,aplace,address,pnumber,cnumber,oname,dtime,DBContract.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED);
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name",name);
                params.put("lname",lname);
                params.put("lnumber",lnumber);
                params.put("violation", violation);
                params.put("aplace", aplace);
                params.put("address",address);
                params.put("pnumber",pnumber);
                params.put("cnumber",cnumber);
                params.put("oname",oname);
                params.put("dtime",dtime);
                return params;
            }
        }
                ;
                MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);
    }
    else
    {
        saveToLocalStorage(name,lname,lnumber,violation,aplace,address,pnumber,cnumber,oname,dtime,DBContract.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED);
    }


}
```

SecondActivity (Where inputs are handled and data passing to the mainactivity)

```
public class ViolatorDetail extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

EditText Name;
Button btnClose;
TextView DTime;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_violator_detail);



    DTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDTime);
    final String currentDT = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    DTime.setText(currentDT);

    btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etfName);
            EditText LName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etlName);
            EditText LNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etlNumber);
            EditText Violation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etViolation);
            EditText Arrestplace = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etaPlace);
            EditText Address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
            EditText PNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etpNumber);
            EditText CNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etcNumber);
            EditText OName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etoName);
            String DT = DTime.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ViolatorDetail.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("firstname", Name.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("lastname", LName.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("licensenumber", LNumber.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("violation", Violation.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("arrestplace", Arrestplace.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("address", Address.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("phonenumber", PNumber.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("contactnumber", CNumber.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("officername", OName.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("datetime", DT);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });





}
```

}

What I want to do is call the "SUBMITNAME" class to the second activity so that no data passing will be done anymore.

Comment: What are you trying to do/avoid here?

Comment: That is a lot of code. Consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.

Comment: the "Intent" is a correct way to move from one activity to another. Most "classic" java way are not guaranteed, object can be swapped etc...

Comment: for this you can store value to static list access it in another activity.!

Comment: From the second activity, The inputs are passed into the MainActivity. From the Main, "SubmitName" class uses the value to store them into the recyclerview. What I want to do is from the SecondActivity instead of passing the data to the Main on button click, I want to call the class "SubmitName" so that I dont need to pass the inputs on the Main anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As other friends mentioned `Intent` is a correct and good way to transfer data between activities. But if you want to avoid writing so much code to transfer data I suggest to create a pure java class (or java bean) and define all needed fields in that class (note: this class should implement `java.io.Serializable` interface). Now you could transfer instances of this class between activities.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is a better way of passing data between activities than Intents. 
What you probably need is encapsulation of passing of extra. You can achieve this by making a static method in the ViolatorDetail class, which accepts as arguments as values you would like to pass, and returns Intent.

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, String ... args){

     Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, ViolatorDetail.this);
     intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STRING_ARGS, args);
     return intent;

}
```

Then in the caller class you make an intent by makeing a static call on that function, and pass values as arguments

```
Intent intent = ViolatorDetail.newIntent(getActivity(), strings)
startActivity(intent);
```

However, in your case, you should probably make a more sensible way of passing data than as array of strings.

Comment: Is there any way I can input data into the recyclerview from the ViolatorDetail.class directly? So that the recyclerview from the MainActivity will only Display its contents directy . Without doing the storing into the recyclerview from MainActivity?

Comment: The only way I see you could achive what you're asking is by doing everithing in one Activity, and hiding and Showing Views. 
But its a bad prectice, and I would advise against it.
Often simpler solution turns out to be more complicated on the long run.
So it's not the question of "can I " but "should I "...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass data between Activities with `Intent`, you can do it by writing certain data in a `file` and when you need it just read from it... I did it like this and I'm still happy i did it that way, it's simple and relatively quick, you just have to care a little about `IOExceptions`.